# IText DocumentException after days of normal behavior

Tags: java, itext, truetype

After a lot of days of perfect working of pdf generation , I am having an error in Production server. Still the same works in local system and test server.

The stack trace is given below.

```
2015-12-07 13:10:35,583 ERROR [STDERR] 
ExceptionConverter: 
2015-12-07 13:10:35,583 ERROR [STDERR] com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: 
../atlas/fonts/arial.ttf is not a true type file.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontSubSet.createTableDirectory(TrueTypeFontSubSet.java:237)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontSubSet.process(TrueTypeFontSubSet.java:133)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TtfUnicodeWriter.writeFont(TtfUnicodeWriter.java:41)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.writeFont(TrueTypeFontUnicode.java:332)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FontDetails.writeFont(FontDetails.java:290)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSharedObjectsToBody(PdfWriter.java:1304)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1212)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:807)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)
```

The file /atlas/fonts/arial.ttf exists,

jar files exists,

the same thing was working 1 week ago.

Did anyone faced this kind of issue? Expecting your help.

Environment is windows , jboss4, java 1.7, itextpdf-5.4.5.jar

Thank you in advance,

**-UPDATE**

After restarting server , pdf is being generated correctly.But may be after 4-5 days, the same issue may occur again.

Comment: Have you tried a later version of iText? I vaguely remember this issue being solved some time ago.

Comment: @MichaëlDemey's advice is most likely correct. See http://itextpdf.com/changelog/556 and https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/commit/db5cc9a6

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response , I'll check with the latest version.

Comment: You might want to check your code for resource leaks, e.g concerning file handles.